# Open source alternative for figma

Tags: website-design, software-recommendation, figma, open-source

I've been using figma a lot on work but now interested for Open Source alternative. Is there anything like that?

Comment: If it's just vector image editor you want, then Inkscape is open source.  It's not quite the same as Figma though.  Figma is vector based, but it's purpose is different, mainly for for UI design. Inkscape is an SVG editor - mainly used for vector graphics.

Comment: This belong on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ not here - but why specifically 'open source'? Do you want to be able to contribute to the code yourself, or just examine it before compile…  or are you confusing open source with 'free'? [Figma also has a free version, btw]

Comment: I am a big fan of Richard Stallman and prefer open source. Mostly I do programming so there are no problems with editors, compilers etc.. But design word is different

Answer (score 4):

**[Penpot](https://penpot.app/)**, while still in beta is a pretty solid open source figma alternative, with loads of features. It is a webapp, works with SVG as a native format and supports interactive prototypes, shared libraries and more.

Comment: Thank you. It is not easy to find source code

Comment: In case someone else is looking for it, source code is here:
https://github.com/penpot/penpot

Answer (score 2):

#### Pencil Project

[Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/) is built for the purpose of providing a free and open-source GUI prototyping tool that people can easily install and use to create mockups in popular desktop platforms (Windows / Mac / Linux / PortableApps.com).

- It is capable of most things that other software like Adobe XD or Figma can do.
- It is open source.
- It can and should be extended with collections and such.
- It lets you edit things like images on the fly using whatever program you want, and it works well.

Comment: Thank you, this one is great!